# zimbra calendar api?! soap java

Tags: java, soap, zimbra

I've a question about the soap-java implementation for zimbra.

I'm writing a java-client which should show calendar entries from a USER.
for example: user=testuser, all entries between 01.01.2011 and 31.01.2011.

I searched the web, but Zimbra SOAP API doesn't have any good documentation...

PS: connection is ok, i could send a mail from my java application

Comment: If you're satisfied with the response you got, please [click the green check mark outline to the left of the answer to accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: of course, sorry ;)! thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the ZMailbox SOAP client, `ZMailbox.getApptSummaries` will give you a `List` of `ZApptSummaryResult` objects representing all appointments overlapping between your start and end dates:

```
List<ZApptSummaryResult> appts;
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
appts = ZMailbox.getApptSummaries(null, startTime, endTime, null, tz, null);
```

If you're using the `zmmailbox` command-line client, use the `gaps` command:

```
zmmailbox gaps {start-date-spec} {end-date-spec}
```

Comment: I think the first one will do.. I don't need something with the command-line ;)
i had the problem with the folderids, before..

Comment: getApptSummaries is not a static method so it cannot be called from a static context !